# How to extract wiki page/site page content using python

Tags: python, sharepoint, text-extraction

I have sharepoint wikis in aspx format url looks something like this https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/SitePages/name.aspx

[In which I wrote random text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVpHZ.png)

I am trying to extract my text I wrote but I am not able to do it using python Office365-REST-Python-Client. Can someone help me on this?

I want to just extract my content but when I use office365 library and read content in aspx file it doesnt show my text content it have some random asp:content and all.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please note that this is not  code-writing or tutorial service, and we ask that questions include a [mcve] including code for wat you've already tried based on your own research, as well as a specific question, problem, or error message so that we can provide specific answers. See also [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.